# Display text from database in label field

Tags: cocoa, sqlite

I am beginner , I have created database called MyDatabase. I want to display some rows from table in a label , my code is, let me know the solution please, thanks in advance

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    MyDatabase *data;
    NSMutableArray *tickerarray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)action
{
    label.text= @"Phase || possession: Jan 2014";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    data=[MyDatabase new];
    tickerarray=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT title FROM news_ticker" :@"title"];

    time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(action) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
@end
```

EDIT:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)OpenMyDatabase: (NSString *)query:(NSString *)column {
    self.databaseName=@"App_Database.sqlite";
    FMDatabase *database=[self openDatabase: self.databaseName];
    [database open];
    NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: query:column];
    [database close];
}
```

Comment: Not enough information.  What currently happens?  How is `[MyDatabase OpenMyDatabase:]` implemented?  Why is its signature so screwy?

Comment: No, not "xcode". This is completely unrelatest do Xcode. Specify if it's Cocoa or Cocoa Touch.

Comment: i just want to display info that i am fetching from the query SELECT title FROM news_ticker, to disaply in a label....just need that code

Comment: Could you please answer my questions and then we will see.

Comment: -(NSMutableArray *)OpenMyDatabase: (NSString *)query:(NSString *)column
{
    
    self.databaseName=@"App_Database.sqlite";
    
    
    FMDatabase *database=[self openDatabase: self.databaseName];
    
    [database open];
    
    NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: query:column];
    
    [database close];
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `OpenMyDatabase` method to return the array (note I changed its return type from `NSMutableArray *` to `NSArray *`):

```
- (NSArray *)OpenMyDatabase:(NSString *)query
                     column:(NSString *)column
{
    self.databaseName=@"App_Database.sqlite";
    FMDatabase *database=[self openDatabase: self.databaseName];
    [database open];
    NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: query:column];
    [database close];
    return nsarr;    // Added
}
```

Comment: @ trojanfoe : if i want to display "nsarr" array in UILabel, then how can i do that ?

Comment: This will display the first item, if there is one: `if ([tickerarray count] > 0) { self.uilabel.text = [tickerarray objectAtIndex:0]; }`

Comment: actually i have 4 items to display randomly